# Rails model #attributes method shows gem inserted association as model attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5, acts-as-taggable-on, acts-as-taggable

I am upgrading a Rails 4.2 application to Rails Version 5.2. We are using the `acts_as_taggable_on` gem (version changed from 4 to 6) for tagging functionality.

Let's say I have a model called Task. If I do `Task.new`, I get the below initialized object.

```
=> #<Task:0x00003fh7398rcg3
 id: nil,
 title: nil,
 description: nil,
 creator_id: nil,
 due_date: nil
 status: "active",
 created_at: nil, 
 updated_at: nil>
```

If I do `Task.new.attributes`, I get

```
 {"id"=>"nil,
 "title"=>"nil,
 "description"=>"nil,
 "creator_id"=>"nil,
 "due_date"=>"nil
 "status"=>""active",
 "created_at"=>"nil, 
 "updated_at"=>"nil,
 "tag_list"=>nil}
```

This `tag_list` is coming from the gem and is expected to be used to set and update the associated tags.

On Rails 4.2, the behavior is as expected. On Rails 5.2, since this add-on attribute shows up as a model attribute, it causes unexpected problems at multiple places.

I went looking and saw that there are changes to ActiveRecord::ModelSchema that may be the cause.

While I was doing that, I did a force-load schema on the Task model.

`Task.send(:load_schema!)`

Output:

```
{
"id"=>#<ActiveRecord::Type::UnsignedInteger:0x00007fc89f01d780 @limit=4, @precision=nil, @range=0...4294967296, @scale=nil>,
"title"=>#<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::AbstractMysqlAdapter::MysqlString:0x00007fc89f0245f8 @limit=610, @precision=nil, @scale=nil>,
"description"=>#<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::AbstractMysqlAdapter::MysqlString:0x00007fc8ab906d40 @limit=1000, @precision=nil, @scale=nil>,
"creator_id"=>#<ActiveRecord::Type::UnsignedInteger:0x00007fc89f01d780 @limit=4, @precision=nil, @range=0...4294967296, @scale=nil>,
"due_date"=>#<ActiveRecord::Type::DateTime:0x00007fc8ab90a5d0 @limit=nil, @precision=0, @scale=nil>,
"status"=>#<ActiveRecord::Enum::EnumType:0x00007fc8a0341870 @mapping={"active"=>0, 
"complete"=>1}, @name="status", ,@scale=nil>,@subtype=#<ActiveModel::Type::Integer:0x00007fc8ab908370 @limit=1, @precision=nil, @range=-128...128, @scale=nil>>,
"created_at"=>#<ActiveRecord::Type::DateTime:0x00007fc8ab90a5d0 @limit=nil, @precision=0, @scale=nil>,
"updated_at"=>#<ActiveRecord::Type::DateTime:0x00007fc8ab90a5d0 @limit=nil, @precision=0, @scale=nil>
"tag_list"=>#<ActsAsTaggableOn::Taggable::TagListType:0x00007fc89fe9e840 @limit=nil, @precision=nil, @scale=nil>
}
```

When I try to see the default attributes by doing `Task._default_attributes`, I still see the tag_list attribute.

```
   "tag_list"=>
    #<ActiveModel::Attribute::WithCastValue:0x00007fc8a03409c0
     @name="tag_list",
     @original_attribute=nil,
     @type=#<ActsAsTaggableOn::Taggable::TagListType:0x00007fc89fe9e840 @limit=nil, @precision=nil, @scale=nil>,
     @value_before_type_cast=nil>}>
```

`tag_list` is definitely not on the model schema, but it is shown as such anyways.

I am stumped how to address this. Appreciate any help!

Comment: I'd check with the gem first since you jumped 2 versions, did u consider posting an issue there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The gem is causing this, since you upgraded 2 major versions a lot of changes were made. Possibly this line is causing it https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on/blob/950c01072b7ab6227d74dc0d0b112f0135281fc2/lib/acts_as_taggable_on/taggable/core.rb#L42.
Your options are to either change your code to support this change or try running the older gem version if it supports Rails 5.

Comment: Thanks! That looks promising. I should have looked into the gem code first before going into Rails. 

I will see how I can tackle this issue, and come back here to accept/report the resolution.

Comment: The end resolution was a hybrid solution where I downgraded the gem version, and had to override a specific method from the `core` module of the gem for total compatibility, and to not break existing use cases in the codebase. 

Thank you, Joel. Your suggestion was right on point and helped me resolve this faster.

Comment: @ShishirK Glad to help! It might be worth it to take it to the gem maintainers if you have the time, I'm not quite sure why it's defined as an attribute...